# как приостановить выполнение программы в Java

Tags: java

как приостановить выполнение программы в Java

Comment: Смотря какую программу. Смотря как надо приостановить. Конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: Thread.sleep(время остановки)

Answer (score 2):

Приостановить программу можно разными способами.

Плохой вариант:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
    //need some sleep...
}
```

А плох он тем, что от машины к машине (на который выполняется программа) время остановки будет разным. К тому же, что более важно, на мой взгляд - в пустую потраченный ресурс процессора (он то делает вычисления...).

Хороший вариант:

```
Thread.sleep(1000); //время остановки в миллисекундах
```

Уже намного лучше - тут Вы и контролируете время остановки, независимо от выполняющей код машины и не заставляете процессор работать в пустую.

[Thread](https://habrahabr.ru/post/164487/) - класс для работы с потоками, в двух словах - любая программа написанная на Java имеет как минимум один поток, поэтому выполнение *Thread.sleep()* сработает **везде**!